# Spring Boot AWS credentials Unauthorized

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-credentials

I m working on a spring boot application and connecting it with Amazon S3 bucket. It is a simple application for uploading videos on aws.

VideoService Class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VideoService {

    private final S3Service s3Service;
    private final VideoRepository videoRepository;


    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file)
    {
        String videoURL = s3Service.uploadFile(file);

        var video = new Video();
        video.setVideoUrl(videoURL);

        videoRepository.save(video);

    }
}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3Service implements FileService{

    public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "****";

    private final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;



    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        var filenameExtension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());

        var key = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + filenameExtension;

        var metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());

        try {
            amazonS3Client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, key, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "An Exception occured while uploading the file");
        }

        amazonS3Client.setObjectAcl(BUCKET_NAME, key, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

        return amazonS3Client.getResourceUrl(BUCKET_NAME, key);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/videos")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VideoController {


    private final VideoService videoService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void uploadVideo(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file)
    {
        videoService.uploadFile(file);
    }
}
```

I already created s3 bucket and access key on aws

The access key and secrey key are stored in VM options:
-Dcloud.aws.credentials.access-key=**** -Dcloud.aws.credentials.secret-key=*****

this is what I get in Postman:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvxR.png)

this is shown in browser:
[Browser localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLnr.png)

Did I miss something?

I was following a tutorial and checked every single code with the completed repo and everything was the same. Instead of giving me 200 status it is giving me 401 status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same use case. One difference is I am using [Amazon S3 Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) - which is the recommended SDK version to use.

**My Controller**.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
            String unqueFileName = uuid + "-" + fileName;

            DynamoDBService dbService = new DynamoDBService();
            S3Service s3Service = new S3Service();
            AnalyzePhotos analyzePhotos = new AnalyzePhotos();
            UploadEndpoint endpoint = new UploadEndpoint(analyzePhotos, dbService, s3Service);
            endpoint.upload(bytes, fileName);
            return "You have uploaded "+fileName;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "File was not uploaded";
    }
```

Notice that i am getting the byte[] of the upload file.

The endpoint.upload() is here:

```
public void upload(byte[] bytes, String name) {
  // Put the file into the bucket.
  s3Service.putObject(bytes, PhotoApplicationResources.STORAGE_BUCKET, name);
  this.tagAfterUpload(name);
}
```

The **s3Service.putObject()** is here:

```
  // Places an image into a S3 bucket.
    public void putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {
        S3Client s3 = getClient();
        try {
            s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .build(),
                RequestBody.fromBytes(data));
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The getClient() is

```
private S3Client getClient() {
        return S3Client.builder()
            .region(PhotoApplicationResources.REGION)
            .build();
    }
```

Now all of this works and can be invoked from Postman:

[image]

Looks like you have Spring Security Dependencies in your POM file (based on your screenshot of a forced login). You should remove them and see if your controller gets the file when setting a break point. You should see:

[image]

Comment: You re, I commented spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server in the dependencies.
Thank you very much sir!